# how to do recursive discriminated unions by value?

Tags: f#

In F# is it possible to have a discriminated union based on both a type and a value?

Here's an attempt at expressing this without knowing what the syntax should look like.

```
type Foo =
    | A of int * Foo
    | B of string where B.name = "1" * Foo
    | C of string where C.name = "2" * Foo
    | Empty
```

Comment: No - this is not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. But, if you want to create a type that will have a `name` property when which is "1" when the type is `B` and "2" when it is `C`, then you can add a member:

```
type Foo =
  | A of int * Foo
  | B of Foo
  | C of Foo
  | Empty
  member x.Name = 
    match x with
    | B _ -> "1"
    | C _ -> "2"
    | _ -> failwith "Name is not available!"
```

If you were hoping to use the numbers in pattern matching, then you can define an active pattern. Say you have a type with just `A` or `B` (which has a name):

```
type Foo = 
  | A of int
  | B of string * Foo
```

Now you can write an active pattern that lets you distinguish between `A`, `B` with name "1" and `B` with name "2":

```
let (|A|B1|B2|) x = 
  match x with
  | A n -> A n
  | B("1", foo) -> B1 foo
  | B("2", foo) -> B1 foo
  | _ -> failwith "Invalid B"
```

If you now have a value `foo`, you can pattern match against these three cases:

```
match foo with
| A n -> ...
| B1 subfoo -> ...
| B2 subfoo -> ...
```

Comment: ty.  +1.  We should have sub types, but instead this is denoted with magic strings.  Could we do this in your match part?  match c, c.Name with
| Foo(x, y), "Foo2" -> printfn "x = %g, y = %g" x y;;

Comment: this question is looking similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288132/how-to-fold-over-a-discriminated-union